# Future assigned to MicroTask or Event Queue?

Tags: dart, async-await, future

In the example below:

```
void main() {
  print('Start');
  Future(
    () {
      print('Mid');
    },
  );
  print('End');
}
```

Above, first `Start` prints, followed by `End` and then `Mid`. `Mid` is printed last due to the `Future` being pushed into the Event Queue to be processed through the Event Loop.

If the above is made into an `async-await` function, where the is `Future` awaited for:

```
void main() async {
  print('Start');
   await Future(
    () {
      print('Mid');
    },
  );
  print('End');
}
```

`Start` prints as usual, followed by `Mid` and then `End`.

In the second example, is `Mid` being printed second due to the `Future` being added to the MicroTask Queue to be executed quickly by the Event Loop, or is it still added onto the Event Queue to be executed by the Event Loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation of `Future(() { ... })` is scheduled in the event queue. It happens in a later event (a timer event, actually, not a microtask event).

That happens in both cases.
Everything up to the scheduling of that computation is the same in both programs. It's what happens afterwards that differs.

In the first program, after the computation has been scheduled, the program goes on to `print('End');` and `main` exits.
At the later timer event, `Mid` is printed and the `Future` completes with `null`. Nobody listens to it, and the program ends.

In the second program, after the computation has been scheduled, the program *awaits* the resulting future.
That means that `then` on that `Future` is called with a callback representing the continuation of the current function.
Then the `main` method returns (a `Future`, since it's `async`) and exits.

When the timer event happens, the program prints `Mid` and then completes the first future with `null`.
The callback added by the `await` gets invoked (maybe immediately, probably in the next microtask), which means that the rest of the `async` main function body executes, which prints `End`.
Then the future returned by `main` is completed (with `null`). Since nobody listens to it, nothing else happens and the program exits.

The difference is not in when `Mid` is printed, but in when `End` is printed. In the second version, you wait for `Mid` to have been printed before continuing to print `End`.

Comment: Also something I've seen [here](https://dart.cn/articles/archive/event-loop#use-the-appropriate-queue-usually-the-event-queue), in the Fun facts about Future section, where they say that if a Future is already complete before invoking the `then()` function, then a task is added to the MicroTask queue which is then executed. Doesn't the Future always have to be complete before the `then()` function is invoked? Is there any circumstance where that is not the case?

Comment: You can call `then` on a future before it completes. The `then` callback will not be invoked until the future completes. That's actually the most common use: Start an asynchronous computation and get an uncompleted future back, await that future (which adds a listener to the future), and at some later point when the computation is done, the future is completed, the callback is called, and the evaluation of the `await` completes with the result.